# Spring Boot Jolokia Post Method Not Allowed

Tags: spring-boot, war, hawtio, jolokia

I have a Spring Boot fat war application that I want to monitor using Hawtio.
I added the following dependency to the pom file to enable the Jolokia agent.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I try to connect to it using Hawtio, I get the following response:

Cannot Connect: Method Not Allowed

{"timestamp":1460830872908,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/jolokia/"}

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Works for me with Jolokia 1.3.3 and Spring Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE using curl to make the POST request. Can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve) that shows the problem?

Comment: Did you solve this?